# How to replicate RedBot's errors?

Tags: http, curl

RedBot is telling me that that I have a couple of serious errors in some of my 
assets:

> - The response status is different when content negotiation happens.
> - An If-None-Match conditional request returned a 404 status. RED hasn't checked other
>     aspects of Content-Negotiation because of this.

I would like to debug this, but I can't duplicate RedBot's errors.  When I try, I get this:

```
# normal negotiated request
xxx@xxx:~$ curl -I -H 'Accept-Encoding:gzip' http://example.com/css/383010.css
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 09 Oct 2013 16:11:12 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Expires: Thu, 09 Oct 2014 16:11:16 GMT
Etag: "f41e1c3f"
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8

# RED says this has a 404?
xxx@xxx:~$ curl -I -H 'Accept-Encoding:' http://example.com/css/383010.css
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 09 Oct 2013 16:11:31 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Expires: Thu, 09 Oct 2014 16:11:31 GMT
Etag: "f41e1c3f"
Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8

# RED also says this is a 404?
xxx@xxx:~$ curl -I -H 'If-None-Match: "f41e1c3f"' http://example.com/css/383010.css
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 09 Oct 2013 16:29:24 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Expires: Thu, 09 Oct 2014 16:29:24 GMT 
Etag: "f41e1c3f"
Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8
```

Does anybody know how to replicate the errors that RED is seeing?